# How do I seperate a string by new lines?

Tags: c#, .net

For example,

```
string example = "Useless info\nI want this line in it's own string or part of a string[]\nUseless info"
```

How do I get only the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var secondLine = example.Split('\n')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string splitting functions:

```
string[] split = example.Split('\n');
```

Each of the array items will be a line. Then you can access the one you want by the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

string[] text=example.split("\n");

text[1] will be the second line content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Split to newline by using `\r\n` or `\n`

```
    string example = "Useless info\nI want this line in it's own string or part of a string[]\nUseless info";
    string[] lines = example.Split(new string[]
    {
    "\r\n", "\n"
    }

    , StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```